# how does data flows through pipe in linux when sorting?

Tags: linux, pipe

suppose I do something like

`cat afile [ | possibly awk or similar to process the file] | sort`

I know data flows something like

```
afile -- stdout -- os buffer -- stdin -- sort
```

When the size of `afile` is small, then maybe `sort` can get the entire contents and sorts them.

However when afile is big, data must flow in chunks.
I know the piped processes run concurrently, so it's possible that sort can receive data and stores them somewhere iteratively.

Does `sort` wait to receive all data before doing the sort?
Possibly writes them onto files.
Then work with those files?

I guess the question can be applied commands other than `sort` that needs the whole data in order to operate.
(How does linux command operate when it receives big data over pipe and it has to get a whole data to perform?, but then it might be too general question to ask..)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-implementation-of-linux-sort-command/

Answer (score 0):

> Does sort wait to receive all data before doing the sort?

This depends on the *actual* implementation of sort.

Our coreutils sort is an old program with many changes. Sorting entrypoint is about here https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c#L3990 , but sorting is done in threads and then merged.

From the look of it, first up to some [buffer size](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c#L308) data are accumulated and send to a thread. So if your data are greater than this buffer size, the sorting starts before data are received.

> Possibly writes them onto files. Then work with those files?

Again, this depends on the size of the data. In GNU sort with have options:

```
   --batch-size=NMERGE
          merge at most NMERGE inputs at once; for more use temp
          files

   --compress-program=PROG
          compress temporaries with PROG; decompress them with PROG
          -d

   -T, --temporary-directory=DIR
          use DIR for temporaries, not $TMPDIR or /tmp; multiple
          options specify multiple directories--compress-program=PROG
          compress temporaries with PROG; decompress them with PROG
          -d
```

These options are really useful when sorting files way bigger than your RAM size.

> can be applied commands other than sort

The above description is *solely related to one specific* implementation of sort in GNU coreutils. Any different implementation of sort may work differently.

In case of `sort` one however has to hold true - it has to receive all the data before outputting anything, because the output has to be sorted.

> How does linux command operate when it receives big data over pipe and it has to get a whole data to perform?

That solely depends on that Linux command. There is no generalization. A pipe is a stream. It's up to you if you have a bucket and accumulate the water of a stream or spill the stream on the floor.